# Accessing HKEY_CURRENT_USER Network subfolders thorugh <winreg.h> functions

Tags: c++, windows, registry

`RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Network\\X", 0, KEY_READ, &key);` does not work, it returns error code `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, accessing something different, however, like `RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Google", 0, KEY_READ, &key);` returns 0, success. I am trying to read the UNC paths `RemotePath` value off of the network drive registries but can't access these regirsty folders. I am sure I didn't mistype the locations.

I tried different paths within `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and those work so it seems to be a problem specific to the Network as far as I can tell. I am running the program as an administrator, tried as normal user as well, same result. I have access to the `Network` itself, it just doesn't seem to find the subfolders for the shared drives. Although I can see them in the registry. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't reproduce (although I used my mapped `J` drive in place of your `X`).

Comment: @AdrianMole is it possible that there’s something specifically restrictive set up on the server I’m trying to access? It seems to affect this particular server and I don’t have another to test it on.